# How to configure cache expiry to none and overflowToDisk="false" in ehcache 3.5 version?

Tags: java, ehcache-3

In ehcache 2.x version I have following configuration.

```
<cache name="basicCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="400"
        eternal="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        overflowToDisk="false">             
    </cache>
```

Following is the corresponding ehcache 3.x version.

```
<ehcache:cache alias="basicCache">
        <ehcache:key-type>java.lang.Long</ehcache:key-type>
    <ehcache:value-type>java.lang.String</ehcache:value-type>           
        <ehcache:resources>
            <ehcache:heap unit=entries">400</ehcache:heap>
        </ehcache:resources>    
    </ehcache:cache>
```

can someone help me to configure below attributes in ehcache 3.5.2 version.

> **eternal="true"** and 
>   **overflowToDisk="false"**

Answer (score 6):

For setting eternal to true, which means the timeouts are ignored and cache will never expire. You can set this by setting expiry as none. Something like below,

```
<cache alias="backupCache">
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
    <expiry>
        <none/>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
        <heap unit="entries">100</heap>
    </resources>
</cache>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

overflowToDisk concept has been removed from the ehcache 3.x version.Refer this link for more details

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ehcache-users/FFHHhRW5hdg

Comment: You say “overflowToDisk concept has been removed from the ehcache 3.x version”.  It seems like that is the basis of the question.  Instead of simply linking to an external resource could you please describe exactly how the question is answered and use the link as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

And you don't have to configure overflowToDisk="false" 
because is disable by default as mentioned on link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542783/12315712